# Scroll an element using display:grid by dragging with variable number of visible items

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following layout, that displays 6x4 squares or 7x4 squares depending on aspect ratio,- if any are hidden from the view they can be viewed by dragging up/down left/right…

It seems with the following grid layout I’m unable to scroll left/right yet up/down works fine, and I’m confused why this would be happening?

*Since my previous question has been closed for no reason, I will respond and answer this question here and give an example how I fixed it.

Run the snippet in full screen and then re-size the window to simulate a vertical or horizontal aspect ratio.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('bottom');

element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {

  if (event.buttons == 1) {
    if (Math.abs(event.movementX) > Math.abs(event.movementY)) {
      if (event.movementX > 0) element.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft - event.movementX;
      if (event.movementX < 0) element.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft - event.movementX;
    } else {
      if (event.movementY > 0) element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop - event.movementY;
      if (event.movementY < 0) element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop - event.movementY;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #046;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bottom {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.white {
  background: white;
}

.div {
  height: 25vh;
  width: 25vw;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .bottom>div {
    width: calc(100vw / 7);
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .bottom>div {
    width: calc(100vw / 6);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bottom" id="bottom">
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>

    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>

    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>

    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>

    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>

    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
    <div class="div yellow"></div>
    <div class="div white"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Regarding your earlier question which was closed ... “Questions that need additional work or that are not a good fit for this site may be closed by experienced community members. Closed questions cannot be answered, but can be edited to make them eligible for reopening.” [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Scrolling shouldn't happen in either direction because you're using dynamic width to size it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The trick in the end was to remove the .bottom element width that was being changed based on aspect ratio and add the width to all div children of the .bottom element, so instead they change depending on aspect ratio, so there's either 6 or 7 horizontally visible squares.

For some reason the .bottom element width being larger than 100vw was interfering with left/right scrolling.